# Module numbers.division in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python has got `number` modules

```
>>> import numbers
<module 'numbers' from 'C:\Python27\lib\numbers.pyc'>
```

and the numbers module has something called `division` - I don't know if it's a function, a attribute, a constant....

```
>>> numbers.division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
```

What is that? No reference to it on the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#module-numbers)
Is that some internal feature of python or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html#module-__future__) features

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
>>> numbers.division is division
True
```

defined in the [`__future__.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fb5fcae0cf1f/Lib/__future__.py#l114) as follows

```
division = _Feature((2, 2, 0, "alpha", 2),
                    (3, 0, 0, "alpha", 0),
                    CO_FUTURE_DIVISION)
```

[The `numbers` module imports `__future__.division` into its namespace](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/34523e53a342/Lib/numbers.py#l8), making it available via regular attribute access.

---

You can get more information about this feature from the [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/):

> The future division statement, spelled `from __future__ import division`, will change the `/` operator to mean true division
>          throughout the module.

This kind of division is default, starting from Python 3+.

Answer (score 0):

[`numbers` does `from __future__ import division`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/numbers.py#L8) which imports the name into scope.

`division` happens to have that value.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on vaultah's answer a little:

When you work in python2, there's an option to do things in a more python3-friendly fashion (the two aren't fully compatible). `from __future__ import division`, for instance. Here's the difference in this case:

```
a p$ ipython2
In [1]: 1 / 2
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: 2 / 3
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: from __future__ import division

In [4]: 1/2
Out[4]: 0.5

In [5]: 2/3
Out[5]: 0.6666666666666666
```

`__future__` is just a magical container that wraps certain other functions; in this case, that other function is held in `numbers`.

Check out the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html

Comment: "\_\_future\_\_ is just a magical container" - what do you mean? And `_Feature` instances are not "functions". And `division` isn't actually "held" in `numbers`.

Comment: I don't think he should have accepted my answer either, I was just trying to give a little context, which wasn't possible in the space of a comment. That context involved some fuzzy definitions, and it's good of you to try to keep people honest, but he can read more in the official docs and get a technical understanding in time. SO isn't really here to replace or regurgitate official documentation, so I just pointed to it and gave a high-level, opinionated overview of the situation.

Comment: @vaultah and a p , I had actually accepted your answer just to motivate and encourage you to answer more, as vaultah is already a veteran here in Stack Overflow. I have enough python knowledge to understand a p answer even knowing the definitions weren't literally correct, however, as well-reminded, this question can be seen in the future by other users so the best answer should be the one that everybody understands. Thank you both for the explanation

Comment: @RafaelCardoso cool, and now all is right with the world again. (people here take their karma very seriously, it seems ;)